# angularjs custom filter on ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Hello I want to create simple search table of data.
I want to highlight if data matched user type input. I done it by doc below since I'm starting using angular i wonder is there any better way? Some custom filter maybe ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      table td{
        padding: 5px;
      }
      .true{
        color: green;
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="filtrController">
      <div>{{search}}<hr/></div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>Param1:</td>
            <td>Param2:</td>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="foo in data | filter:search">
            <!--<td ng-class="{true:'true',false:''}[search === foo.Name]">{{foo.Name}}</td>-->
            <td ng-class="customFilter(search,foo.Name)">{{foo.Name}}</td>
            <td ng-class="customFilter(search,foo.param1)">{{foo.param1}}</td>
            <td ng-class="customFilter(search,foo.param2)">{{foo.param2}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        myApp.controller('filtrController',function ($scope)
        {
          $scope.customFilter = function(search,searchTo)
          {
            if(search != '')
            {
              if(searchTo.indexOf(search) > -1) return 'true';
              return '';
            }
          };
          $scope.data =
                  [
                    {
                      Name:'name foo1',
                      param1:'param of foo1',
                      param2:'param 2 of foo1'
                    },
                    {
                      Name:'name foo2',
                      param1:'param of foo2',
                      param2:'param 2 of foo2'
                    },
                    {
                      Name:'name sfoo3',
                      param1:'param of foo3',
                      param2:'param 2 of foo3'
                    },
                  ]
        });


    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to custom filter like this:

```
$scope.customFilter = function(data, searchFor) {
  if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(searchFor)) return data;
  angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
    if(angular.equals(item, searchFor)) item.highlighted = true;
  });
  return data;
}
```

and html like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="foo in data | customFilter:{something:1}" ng-class="{highlighted: foo.highlighted}">
```

**Update:**

So, I just need to explain my approach in more details. You have data some of which is needed to be highlighted. So you need to set new property in your data and highlight it (using css and ng-class) if property set to true.
For setting this property you can create custom filter that takes your data array, changes it internal state by setting this property and return this array as result. This is what I implemented for you.

**Update#2**

Same behaviour as ng-filter needed. So [here it is](http://plnkr.co/edit/LZEy8u32Fm4birij0SO5?p=preview).

Comment: is that filter ? or just a function ? I try doing my own filter still i dont know how to do it any help ? var myAppFilters = angular.module('myAppFilters',[])
              .filter('customFilter',function()
              {
                return function(input,search)
                {
                          .........  
                  return input;
                };
              })
      ;

Comment: Same story with custom filter. Move my code there and it'll be available not only in this controller, but app wide. Still same story. Still I'll fix one probable mistake.

Comment: I will try thx. Still I run my own filter the point is to change a bit code matched element. I can console.log the result but i don't know how to pass it into array can you help in that ? code is on next comment...

Comment: [code]angular.module('highModule',[]) .filter('high',function() { returnfunction(input,dataSearch) { varfiltered=[]; angular.forEach(input,function(input) { varres=[]; res=angular.forEach(input,function(input) { //console.log(input); if(input.indexOf(dataSearch)>-1) { console.log('<span>'+input+'</span>'); } }) //console.log(res); filtered.push(res); }); returnfiltered; } });[/code]

Comment: Please read my answer one more time. I'll update it to you right away.

Comment: ok i can't manage it. I replace my function on Yours and replace tr row still not working and console shows error. Can you please adjust my example on jsfiddle ?

Comment: Yep. Two hours from now

Comment: Ok I give up. I have no idea how to manage this by filter..... I was able to convert and console.log data exactly as I wanted but i cant return it...

Comment: I am here now. Give me your fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/felek/4aF8s/ not working for some reason init mayby include ng-app neded

Comment: ok 2 thinks never seen before in examples: .filter('customFilter', function($filter) { //passing $filter ?? why ? and angular.forEach($filter('filter')(input, search, false), function(found) {
                found.highlight = true;

              }); that function

Comment: I inject $filter service to have access to it in my code. Then I use it for same type of filtering as in templates. And after that I set highlight for all filtered values.